# Why setPreferredSize does not change the size of the button?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, size, jbutton

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestGrid {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Colored Trails");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 9));
        panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(9*30-20,4*30));

        JButton btn;
        for (int i=1; i<=4; i++) {
            for (int j=1; j<=4; j++) {
                btn = new JButton();
                btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
                panel.add(btn);
            }

            btn = new JButton();
            btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 10));
            panel.add(btn);

            for (int j=1; j<=4; j++) {
                btn = new JButton();
                btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
                panel.add(btn);
            }

        }
        mainPanel.add(panel);
        frame.add(mainPanel);

        frame.setSize(450,950);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I suppose to have a table of buttons with 4 rows and 9 columns. And the middle column should be narrower that other columns.  I tried `Dimension(30, 10)` and `Dimension(30, 10)` both have no effect on the width of the middle column. Why?

Comment: Read the tutorial. You've bee given the link to the Swing tutorial multiple times. This is clearly explained in the tutorial on "How to Use Grid Layout". Quit flooding the forum with all these questions until you do some basic reading of your own. The is now 7 questions related to layout managers in the last couple of days. It boggles my mind the people continue to answer these questions, especially when you don't event accept answers given.

Comment: @camickr, nobody force you to answer my questions. There are people which have questions and there are people which are ready to answer this questions. And these people can find common language and way to cooperate. If you do not understand why it works, just do not take a part in this. And do not disturb other people.

Comment: I understand the way it works. You do some research and when you have a problem you post a questio asking for help. We are not here to do the reading for you. If you make an effort we will make an effort.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Layout managers are free to ignore the preferred size. Specifically, `GridLayout` will always make each cell in the grid exactly the same size (it's a pretty useless layout manager for that reason).

You'll have to use a different layout manager, such as nested `BoxLayout` or a `GroupLayout`.

Answer (score 2):

GridLayout is quite inflexible in that each and every cell is the same size, typically honoring the largest height and width settings of any object added to the grid.

If the rows and/or columns need to have varying sizes you should use GridBagLayout.

Answer (score -2):

`setPreferredSize` will not change the size of the button until dimension is set by using Dimension.

Example:-

`Dimension dim = new Dimension(20,20), then use setPerferredSize(dim).`

Comment: In this case setting Dimension won't help. GridLayout is being used which doesn't fully honor setPreferredSize. GridLayout sets all heights and widths the same based on the largest width and height. Also, note that the largest height and width does not have to come from the same component.